# CSS: div p, a not applying to a tag

Tags: html, css

I have a very simple HTML with CSS code, don't understand why, the css rule isn't applied to the a tag, but it works on p tags. If I wrap the a tag inside a p tag, the css works, but I can't understand why it doesn't work without wrapping it.

Here's a full example http://jsfiddle.net/juaning/84Xn2/

css: `div p, a {
    margin-top: 35px;
    font-size: 24px;
}`

html: `<div class="family">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/codecademy">Luigi</a>
</div>`

Comment: inline elements (such as an anchor) don't accept a margin property

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The box model of an `a` tag is different than the box model of a `p` tag. Add this one line:

```
div p, a {
    display: inline-block;
```

By default, an `a` tag has the `display: inline` box model, so that you can easily place it in the same line as regular text (i.e. inside a `p`). The `p` tag is more of an entity on it's own, always being a 'block' or 'box' of text, therefore the `p` has `display: block;` by default.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ECAbd/1/

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question.  I would like to point out that you could stay consistent and put a p tag in the Luigi div and then the a tag inside of that.

Comment: Which would be a cleaner solution :), or adding a class to the `a` tag so you don't mess with other `a` tags on your page.

Comment: Hi, thanks man, can't accept the answer as correct yet, but thanks for clarifying that for me!

Answer (score 2):

`a` tag is an `inline` element, and `p` is a block level element, margin won't apply to inline element, and hence you need to make your `a` tag, block or `inline-block`.

```
div p, a {
    margin-top: 35px;
    font-size: 24px;
    display: block;
}
```

Now, here, again it depends, what you want your `a` tag to be, if you want multiple `a` tags to line up inside your `div` you will have to use `inline-block` and if you use `display: block;` it will take entire horizontal space and will render another element below it.

Take for example you've a horizontal menu, where you line up your elements, you will probably use `ul` and `li` but suppose you take `div` for each menu item, you may need `display: inline-block;`, this will have all properties of block level element, but it will render them inline leaving the other space empty for other elements to take up, but if you want to render each element below one another, you need to use `display: block;`(not for `div` tag or `p` tag, they are block level elements by default, inorder to change their behavior, you need to mention that in your CSS)

[List of block level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Block-level_elements)

[List of inline elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Inline_elements)

Answer (score 1):

Anchors have `display: inline` by default, while paragraphs are (if I recall) `display: inline-block`. Margins do not apply to inline elements. You can easily fix this by explicitly setting `display` to `inline-block` in your CSS.

Comment: Paragraphs have display `block` by default. Not `inline-block`. http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html

Answer (score 0):

Add this rule to the css -

```
display: block;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution replace your code "div p, a" by following

> div p, div a {
>       font-size: 24px;
>       line-height: 100px;
>       display: inline; }

Notice I used line-height (same as box height) to make vertical align center rather than margin-top. But this is not the solution for multi line.